# Magento 2 get base url (current store) in admin static block/page?

Tags: magento2, category, static-block, base-url, link

How can I get (current store) Base Url in CMS block/page in Magento 2? Actually, I am displaying category names in the footer by using static block. For that how can I give the Category Url links in admin static block?

Comment: Refer link may get help http://www.emagentosupport.com/2018/12/magento-2-add-store-url-in-static-block.html

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can add current store URL in static block.

```
{{store url=""}}
```

If you wanto add store url with category URL.

```
{{store url="category-url"}}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can add store URL in static block:

```
<a href="{{store direct_url='identifier'}}">Your link</a>
```

Comment: This is working for Magento 2.4 and above versions

Answer (score 0):

{{store url="category-url"}}